# Win7 makes my fat32 fs corrupt when i create some files in linux, in dual boot environment

Tags: windows-7, linux, filesystems, cache

all

I setup a dual boot environment with linux 3.9.2 and win7.
I used a fat32 partition to share some files between them.
After booting into linux, create/delete some files and then switch back to win7. chkdsk tells me some file are corrupt.

I use these option to mount the fat32 partition on linux:
rw,noatime,gid=1000,uid=1000,fmask=133,dmask=022

Is something wrong with the options i use for mounting?

Comment: Verify you have the current FAT32 drivers for your linux instalation.

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue of Rapidboot HDD Accerlator from lenovo on EE3 laptops!

According to :[this](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/What-are-RapidBoot-Shield-and-RapidBoot-HDD-Accelerator/ta-p/793027), rapidboot will build cache for important boot data. these data may contains fat or something else about filesystem. this cache fools win7, it will no longer access to real data on the disk until the cache says i'm invalid.

rapidboot hdd will not know my changes to that fat32 partition, so its cache won't either.
consistency is lost. at least win7 will read/write wrongly per the cache. fsck/chkdsk will report that inconsistency and try to fix it so that make things worse, corrupt more files.

turning off rapidboot hdd accerlator solves my problem.